# Port of Spain to Porlamar, Margarita - any direct flights?

Tags: air-travel, venezuela, trinidad-and-tobago

Any advise who is flying, how frequently and how to contact the operator/carrier? I have not find any information on the internet. Any info is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The best starting point for the less busy airports is to consult their official pages such as [Port of Spain](http://www.tntairports.com/piarco/departures-test.php), which lists the flight VO 4005 departed at 5:30PM by [Conviasa Airlines](http://www.conviasa.aero/2012/site.php), which seems to be the only airline flying the direct route.

[Parlomar's Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Caribe_%22Santiago_Mari%C3%B1o%22_International_Airport) lists 2 other airlines that make such a flight but I think they are private charters for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

My usual go-to resource for flight schedules out of a particular airport is kayak: All you need is the IATA airport code for your origin (in this case POS) and you can just go straight to:

http://www.kayak.com/direct/POS/2014-01

to see that there are three flights a week, operated by Conviasa. You can then check on the airline's website for more information.